# How to configure Eclipse EGit to use custom proxy settings?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I'm behind a corporate firewall, so most of the time (e.g. Eclipse updates) I want to be going through a proxy. However, the servers I pull from in Git are all internal. I currently have to change my proxy settings every time I switch, but I'd like to set it up so that EGit uses a direct connection.

My guess is that it's just not a feature EGit has, but can anyone think of a workaround maybe?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

EGit should follow the General > Network configuration settings.
If you set that Network mode to "Manual", you can:

- set your proxy (with authentication)
- add sites you want in "no_proxy" (in order to *not* try to contact a proxy)

This seems also valid for ssh protocol, as illustrated by [bug 349702](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=349702).

Comment: Thanks! I misinterpreted what the Proxy bypass was meant for. It works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

For me the answer of VonC didn't work (Eclipse Neon.2). I had to enter my proxy at the Settings under:

Window -> Preferences

and then
General -> Network connections

Also note that some proxy servers block the git:// and ssh:// protocols. If you face issues, try to use the https:// or http:// protocol.