# How to configure Eclipse EGit to use a proxy _only_ for specific domains?

Tags: eclipse, git, ssh, proxy

I know that the general Eclipse EGit proxy question has been [asked and answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615121/how-to-configure-eclipse-egit-to-use-custom-proxy-settings), but I have the opposite situation:

I need to use a specific SOCKS5 proxy *only* when accessing git repos (via `ssh`) in one particular domain, and need to not use a proxy for all other domains.

This makes it impractical/impossible to use a generic proxy and bypass the domains for which I don't want to use a proxy.

What I've tried (in the Team → Git → Configuration → User Settings list):

```
core.sshCommand = "C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink" -load "via proxy"
```

where the `via proxy` PuTTY session sets up the SOCKS5 proxy configuration to enable `plink` to connect to a remote ssh site over the existing SOCKS5 proxy.

This command works from the command line:

```
C:\Users\myaccount\git>"c:\program files (x86)\PuTTY\plink" -load "via proxy" git@git.my.domain info
hello my.user.name@git.my.domain, this is git@gitserver running gitolite3 v3.6.3-10-g4be7ac5 on git 1.7.1
…
```

However, when I try to access a git repository from eclipse/EGit, I receive the following "Problem Occurred" report:

```
git@git.my.domain:myrepo.git: unknown host

org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException
```

and the "Details" pain shows:

```
git@git.my.domain:myrepo.git: unknown host
git@git.my.domain:myrepo.git: unknown host
```

In any case, this is only a workaround and will only work as long as I only access Git repositories via ssh from this one domain and all other domains are accessed via https or other protocols.

Anyone have any ideas how I can get this to work?

Comment: This might be a quoting problem so the arguments shift.  You may want to move the command inside a batch file so you can control it better.

Comment: I created a batch file and had the batch file also output to a debugging file.  The debugging file isn't even getting created.

Comment: Does eGit/jGit even support the `core.sshCommand` configuration?